# xpath - following-sibling question

Tags: python, xpath

basic question that i'm missing something.

have the text html

```
    <tr ><td class="CourseTitle" >foo </td></tr>
<tr ">      <th >Code</th><th >Type</th>    </tr>
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><td ">40000</td><td ">40000</td></tr>
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><td ">40001</td><td ">40000</td></tr>
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><td ">40002</td><td ">40000</td></tr>
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><td ">40003</td><td ">40000</td></tr>
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><td ">40004</td><td ">40000</td></tr>


<tr class="blue-bar" bgcolor="navy"><td colspan="16"></td></tr>

<tr "><td class="CourseTitle" >asaa     </td>   </tr>
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><td ">4sd0003</td><td ">40000</td></tr>
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><td ">400sd04</td><td ">40000</td></tr>
```

i'm trying to figure out a way to get all the subsequent tr/td following the "tr" that has a "td" with a @class="CourseTitle"

something like:

```
/html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[@class="CourseTitle"]/../following-sibling::tr//td[@class="CourseTitle"]
```

only gets a list of all the trs with the matching td/@class which isn'twhat I'm going for.

I've been trying to figure out how you get the siblings, when a child of the sibling matches the condition..

I'm testing this in python, using the libxml libs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

url='http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/?YearTerm=2011-92&Breadth=ANY&Dept=CHEM&CourseNum=&Division=ANY&CourseCodes=&InstrName=&CourseTitle=&ClassType=ALL&Units=&Days=&StartTime=&EndTime=&MaxCap=&FullCourses=ANY&FontSize=100&CancelledCourses=Exclude&Bldg=&Room=&Submit=Display+Web+Results'
doc=lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))

# For debugging
# doc=lh.parse('/tmp/Schedule of Classes.html')


for td in doc.xpath('//tr/td[@class="CourseTitle"]'):
    title=td.xpath('font/b/text()')[0]
    print(title)
    keys=td.xpath('../following-sibling::tr/th/text()')
    for row in zip(*[iter(td.xpath('../following-sibling::tr/td'))]*len(keys)):
        vals=[s.text_content() for s in row]
        print(dict(zip(keys,vals)))
```

yields

```
GENERAL CHEMISTRY
{'Status': 'OPEN', 'Web': u'\xa0', 'Code': '40060', 'Rstr': 'A', 'Textbooks': 'Bookstore', 'Max': '24', 'WL': 'n/a', 'Enr': '15', 'Sec': 'D10', 'Time': u'F \xa0 12:00-12:50p', 'Units': '0', 'Place': 'RH 108', 'Instructor': 'ARASASINGHAM, R.', 'Type': 'Dis', 'Nor': '0', 'Req': '14'}
...
UNIVERSITY TEACHING
{'Status': 'OPEN', 'Web': u'\xa0', 'Code': '41533', 'Rstr': 'K and S', 'Textbooks': 'Bookstore', 'Max': '150', 'WL': '0', 'Enr': '25', 'Sec': 'A', 'Time': u'M \xa0 12:00-12:50p', 'Units': '1-4', 'Place': 'TBA', 'Instructor': 'TOBIAS, D.BOROVIK, A.', 'Type': 'Tut', 'Nor': '0', 'Req': '26'}
```

Comment: hi @unutbu  tried your solution. didn't generate any siblings. i'm not sure why you say that the "tr" I provided aren't siblings. They're the same level in the tree.. if you need, I can provide a better example in a paste, but didn't want to go overboard here.

Comment: @bobby 1: Can you post some more context around your posted HTML?

Comment: hi @unutbu  - I pasted more of the actual html --- http://fpaste.org/2I8d/  <<   and also provided a link in the paste to the actual page  - thanks

Comment: tried the  >> /html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[@class="CourseTitle"]/../following-sibling::tr[not(td[@class="CourseTitle"])] << and it lists "all" the sibling tr/tds.. excluding the ones with the "CourseTitle"..

Comment: @bobby 1: After looking at the full HTML, I'm suggesting a different strategy -- instead of one large XPath, it uses a number of XPaths to pick out the relevant pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an XPath expert by any mean, but you could always try:

```
//tr/td[@class="CourseTitle"]/../following-sibling::tr/td[not(@class="CourseTitle")]/..
```